# Getting exception while using CPLEX six dimentional variables

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, cplex

I am getting the following exception while trying to print a the following code. Can anyone advise what happened?

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < numberOfNodes; j++) {
    for (int t = 0; t < noOfTimePeriods; t++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < numberOfNodes; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < numberOfNodes; l++) {
          for (int t1 = 0; t1 < noOfTimePeriods; t1++) {
            if (cplex.getValue(x[i][j][t][k][l][t1]) != 0)
              System.out.println("x["+i+"]["+j+"]["+t+"]["+k+"]["+l+"]["+t1+"] : "
                + cplex.getValue(x[i][j][t][k][l][t1]));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
ilog.cplex.IloCplex$UnknownObjectException: CPLEX Error: object is unknown to IloCplex
    at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.getValue(IloCplex.java:7594)
    at SCHL.t16Model(SCHL.java:358)
    at SCHL.executeModel(SCHL.java:23)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to have a look at the example facility.java in `CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\examples\src\java`.

And there you will see:

```java
// Create variables. We have variables
// open[j]        if location j is open.
// supply[i][j]]  how much client i is supplied from location j
IloNumVar[] open = cplex.boolVarArray(nbLocations);
IloNumVar[][] supply = new IloNumVar[nbClients][];
for (int i = 0; i < nbClients; i++)
    supply[i] = cplex.numVarArray(nbLocations, 0.0, 1.0);
```

or with 4 dimensions:

```java
IloCplex mycplex = new IloCplex();
int Ncd = 2;
int Nbv = 6;
int T = 4;
IloNumVar[][][][] y = new IloIntVar[Ncd][][][];
for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i] = new IloIntVar[Ncd][][];
    for (int j = 0; j < y[i].length; j++) {
        y[i][j] = new IloIntVar[Nbv + 1][];
        for (int k = 1; k < y[i][j].length; k++) {
            y[i][j][k] = mycplex.boolVarArray(T + 1);
            for (int t = 1; t < T; t++) {
                IloRange myConstraint2 = mycplex.addEq(y[i][j][k][t], 1);
                mycplex.add(myConstraint2);
            }
        }
    }
}
mycplex.solve();
for (int i = 0; i < Ncd; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Ncd; j++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < Nbv; k++) {
            for (int t = 1; t < T; t++)
                System.out.printf("valeur = " + mycplex.getValue(y[i][j][k][t]));
        }
    }
}
```